# Congratulations, André!

Tags: discussion, reputation, specific-user, celebration

Since yesterday, the number of 100k+ users on MSE has **doubled**, courtesy of [André Nicolas](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6312/andre-nicolas?tab=reputation).

I think congratulations are in order!

Comment: (But somebody apparently doesn't?!)

Comment: Thanks for all the hard work you put into math.SE André, I've always noticed and appreciated it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Thanks! And let me hasten to add that I wasn't the one downvoting.

Comment: Congratulations, André!

Comment: Congratulations Mate. Good on ya.

Comment: Congratulations indeed! That's a nearly unbelievable level of contribution.

Comment: @hjg: It's interesting that an unregistered member who's activity on the site spans for merely two months can so decisively say what is the meta for. If you look at the past two years or so of history on the meta, you will see that the meta site *does* make a platform for such announcements, when they are rare and important. And a second 100k user is an important point. It means that the site is quite big already.

Comment: Contragulations, André! Also on the 100% increase in [100k replegion](http://xkcd.com/1102/)!

Comment: What kind of answer OP expects?

Answer (score 33):

Thank you for the post about $100$K. It is more a matter of longevity than anything else.

Soon there will be several more. But no one will ever match the percentage increase that Arturo Magidin achieved.

Comment: I'm sure if Arturo were here he would deny to have achieved any well-defined percentage increase at all.

Comment: Congratulations! :)

Comment: Congratulations! :)

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Longevity’s necessary, but there’s also a *lot* of work. (I think that I’m qualified to judge the amount of work involved. :-)) Congratulations!

Comment: Congrats Andre. Did you receive any swag from stack-exchange for being *more awesome*? Just curious :)

Comment: @Marvis A half year ago got an e-mail about "swag." didn't do anything about it. More recently, got a congratulations e-mail about more swag. didn't do anything about it.

Comment: Who is arturo magidin ?