# Congratulations, Asaf!

Tags: discussion, reputation, specific-user

Congratulations to Asaf for joining the 100k club ([Arturo](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3558/congratulations-arturo?rq=1), [Qiaochu](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6515/congratulations-qiaochu?rq=1), [André](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6319/congratulations-andre?rq=1), [Brian](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6648/congratulations-brian-m-scott?rq=1), [Did](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9381/congratulations-did-hits-the-100k?rq=1)). Your contributions are always appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Also, this has been done for every other member of the 100K club (see "related" links).  It would seem that some people don't like Asaf...  I, for one, congratulate him!

Comment: That was some skillful maneuvering  at the finish line, accepting two answers on old questions for the total of  +4...

Comment: Mazeltov, Asaf!

Comment: Congratulations Asaf!! (I am at a loss to add something as witty and/or humorous as you manage to do with uncanny regularity!)

Comment: Congrats, Asaf!!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Since Asaf likes jokes, I thought of downvoting this question. But too late, two funny people already did. So +1(000 000), Asaf!

Comment: Congratulations, Asaf!!

Comment: @40votes Oh, do you imply that Asaf not only *crossed* the 100k line but in fact *hit* it (for a probably very short moment)?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That's what the screenshot in the post shows, right? And Asaf's reputation timeline shows the actions I described, which made the rep score divisible by 10 right as it approached 100K.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I checked because Asaf mentioned this by email, he hit 100,000 exactly. That lasted for several minutes at a minimum. His email did not mention the exact figure, but that was in place when I looked. No, I'm looking at the email thread, I asked him at 99.9K

Comment: Congratulations, Asaf!

Comment: Congratulations, Asaf! You answered my second question on the site and since then I always enjoy your posts! Thanks for sharing your knowledge with us.

Comment: מזל טוב , Asaf!

Answer (score 34):

$$\begin{array}{l}\text{Hundred Thousand, where the wind comes sweepin' down the plain,}\cr 
\text{And the wavin' wheat can sure smell sweet, When the wind comes right behind the rain,}\cr 
\text{Hundred Thousand, Ev'ry night my honey lamb and I,}\cr
 \text{Sit alone and talk and watch a hawk makin' lazy circles in the sky.}\cr 
\text{We know we belong to the land}\cr 
\text{And the land we belong to is grand!}\cr
\text{And when we say}\cr
\text{Yeeow! Aye-yip-aye-yo-ee-ay!}\cr
\text{We're only sayin'}\cr
\text{You're doin' fine, Hundred Thousand!}\cr
\text{Hundred Thousand, H.T.!}\end{array}$$

Comment: http://www.stlyrics.com/lyrics/oklahoma/oklahoma.htm

Comment: What else could one possibly add?